# Paypal Integration in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, paypal, cakephp-2.0

i really can't seem to make it.. im frustrated learning this for almost three days now however im still trying. What i actualy wanna happen is this:

Customer fills up order form

After filling up, he will click the "Buy now" button at the bottom of my page.

I would like to extract the data the user have entered from the order form and save it to may database.

Dunno if it has something to do with the IPN or PDT stuff. The point is im cant move forward for three days now. I wanna know how this starts of perhap ah pseudocode of what i can actually do with this?

I mean where can i possibly start. Okay i downloaded the plugin and extracted it in /app/Plugin/, and then?  I have read the manual and tried various tutorials but it's not getting me anywhere. Im totally a beginner. Please help.

---

this is an update with im doing.

i got this error:

```
Error: PaypalIpn.PaypalHelper could not be found.

Error: Create the class PaypalHelper below in file: C:\xampp\htdocs\wifidrivescanportal\app\Plugin\paypal_ipn\View\Helper\PaypalHelper.php

<?php
class PaypalHelper extends AppHelper {

}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? A bit of code might help us know where to start.

Comment: i was just able to put the plugin into cakephp but i dunno how would i start using it. nothing worked from the tutorials i followed. Perhaps im missing something big.

Comment: i mean as per indicated in what i have read to extract the plugin into plugins folder in cake and then after that, nothing is working.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said this is cake 2.x, make sure that your plugin is loaded:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#installing-a-plugin

Since cake 2.0, plugins need this to work. Also, make sure that the plugin you're using is made for Cake 2.x versions, not an earlier one, because they are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did'nt configure your global bootstrap. Add the following line to your cakephp/app/Config/bootstrap.php and it should work!

```
CakePlugin::load('PaypalIpn', array('bootstrap' => array('paypal_ipn_config'), 'routes' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt mention your cake version - which you ALWAYS should.
but I assume it is 2.x

so why aren't you naming your plugin after the convention?
paypal_ipn should be PaypalIpn

Comment: there, i got a different error now..
Notice (8): Use of undefined constant APP_PATH - assumed 'APP_PATH' [APP\Plugin\PaypalIpn\View\Helper\PaypalHelper.php, line 16]
Fatal error: Class 'PaypalIpnConfig' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wifidrivescanportal\app\Plugin\PaypalIpn\View\Helper\PaypalHelper.php on line 20